# can't clone sql object in fuel php

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'd like to clone sql　query　object.

```
$base_query = DB::select()->from('manage_mobile');
$listquery　= clone $base_query;
```

However this causes fatal error.

```
: Undefined variable: listquery
```

$base_query is surely object.I checked it by var_dump.

How can I solve this problem？

Comment: Do a `var_dump(get_class($base_query))` and see if that class or any parents implement the clone method.

Comment: This is `var_dump(get_class($base_query));` **string(39) "Fuel\Core\Database_Query_Builder_Select"** It seems that the clone method wasn't implemented.

Comment: Gotta go to sleep, gave you a +1 for more exposure. If by morning its not answered, I'll research the object.

Comment: THANKS! I'll waiting for the solution.

Comment: The line containing that clone statement can not result in that error message. You only get an "Undefined variable" notice (and not a fatal) if you access a non-defined variable. This line however is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to clone the query object ? if you want to clone the result you can just use:

```
$r = DB::query("SELECT * FROM manage_mobile")->execute()->as_array();
$c = clone $r;
```

this should work since $r is a regular array.